# Find all imported interfaces that object supports

Tags: reflection, go

I have an object like `os.Stdout` and I want to know if it supports `io.WriteCloser` on my platform. I can get the type of my object, but it doesn't tell me anything about interfaces.

```
package main

import ("fmt"; "reflect"; "os")

func main() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(os.Stdout))
}
```

This code prints `*os.File` to console.

I can manually lookup if `os.File` matches `io.WriteCloser` methods, but I am curious to get all interfaces that this object supports.

Comment: "All interfaces" at runtime is practically impossible. Checking a single known one is done by a "type assertion".

Comment: @Volker this sounds like a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

*It's not an exactly answer on the question, because it is not for runtime. Anyway I think it maybe useful*

Take a look on https://golang.org/lib/godoc/analysis/help.html
`godoc` has static analysis features. And it can display your type implements relations.

For example you can run `godoc -http=:8081 -analysis=type` and get all your packages documentation with type analysis.

Comment: I appreciate you pointer, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just missed out that you are talking about runtime

Comment: Well, I am new to Go, so I used to insert stuff directly into code to inspect it. But if there is a command line that gives me this info - I guess that would qualify too. But of course in something like Python getting this info dynamically provides some flexibility for advanced things with modular/plugin structure like Twisted, Trac etc.

Comment: Anyway try to use `godoc -http=:8081 -analysis=type`. Then on localhost:8081 you can expore all packages with type analysis. Go uses duck typing, so it can be difficult in runtime, but I'm not sure =)

Comment: That's something at least. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment from @Volker regarding type assertions, that would look like this:

```
_, implements := interface{}(os.Stdout).(io.Reader)
```

It casts `os.Stdout` to an `interface{}` type and then attempts to assert that it is an `io.Reader`. Type assertions return two values; the first is the asserted value (or nil if assertion fails) and the second is a boolean indicating if the assertion was successful or not. If you omit capturing the second return value then a failed assertion will cause a panic.

For alternative, possibly more generic or runtime requirements the types package may have some useful functions based on reflection: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/types